# I am novice to python , i want import the first two colums data of a .csv file into a dictionary using python

Tags: python-2.7, file, dictionary, python-import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BNTu.jpg)     import csv

```
 mydict = {}  
 with open('factbook.csv', mode='r') as infile:
     reader = csv.reader(infile)
     for rows in reader:
        if rows <=2:
           mydict.append(reader)
           print(mydict)
```

factbook.csv

Country        Area(sqkm)

Afghanistan    647500
Akrotiri       123
Albania        28748
Algeria        2381740
AmericanSamoa  199

Comment: Can you be clearer as to what you want to achieve? You want to make a list of dictionaries or disctionary of lists? On a different note, have you considered using `pandas` data frames?

Comment: nope i dont know pandas.. i need to store them to access their values, thats what i need. anything better to traverse will be better.

Comment: Can you add the structure of the desired dictionary?

Comment: factbook.csv

Country                Area(sqkm)

Afghanistan         647500
Akrotiri                 123
Albania                28748
Algeria                 2381740
AmericanSamoa 199

Comment: one data below another

Answer (score 0):

After the line

```
          reader=csv.reader(infile)
```

just add

```
          fields = reader.next()
          for row in reader:
              mydict[row[0]]=row[1]
```

This should do.

Comment: mydict[row[0]]=row[1]   
IndexError: list index out of range ... it throws me an error saying that index list out of range..

Comment: in the loop (for loop) just print len(row) before the line mydict[row[0]]=row[1] and check if it is 2.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to make a dictionary of country names as keys and area as values. 
So here goes the code:

```
import csv

mydict = {}  
with open('factbook.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',')
    header = reader.next()
    for rows in reader:
        if len(rows) <= 2:
            mydict[rows[0]] = rows[1] # This adds/overwrites keys in a dictionary

print(mydict)
```

The dictionary will be created as follows:

```
{'Afghanistan': '647500', 'AmericanSamoa': '199', 'Akrotiri': '123', 'Albania': '28748', 'Algeria': '2381740'}
```

Comment: mydict[rows[0]] = rows[1]            
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: but your answer is exactly i want!! .. how can i resolve this error??

Comment: For the dataset you gave in the question, this works. Does your file have different values?

Comment: nope this is a trucated data for just 5 rows.. but i have 256 rows and 40 column data ... the values are the same'

Comment: What are the delimiters in your dataset? You have given white spaces in your question. Are they spaces or commas? Also, try printing `rows` you read from csv to find the issue.

Comment: wait i will add the csv file in the question

Comment: screenshot is added above

Comment: @GowdhamGowD I was expecting a csv opened in a text editor, not as spreadsheet. But I think the edit I have made should do the trick. Try the latest edit. 

Also, edit the csv you have added in your question to be delimited by `,` and not a " " (space).